# How to verify directly that the solution satisfies ODE and IVC's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

Suppose we have the initial value problem $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=h(t),$$ for some given function $h$, with initial conditions $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.

Using the boundary conditions $G(0;\tau)=G'(0;\tau)=0$, I have derived the Green's function:

$$G(t;\tau)=
\begin{cases}
0,&0\le t<\tau,\\
t-\tau,&\tau<t<\infty.
\end{cases}
$$
Then I used the general equation for the solution of the problem,
$$y(t)=\int_0^\infty G(t;\tau)h(\tau)d\tau$$ to get

$$y(t)=t\int_0^th(\tau)d\tau-\int_0^t\tau h(\tau)d\tau.$$

But, how can I verify directly that this function satisfies both the differential equation and the initial value conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check it, find the derivatives:  by the "fundamental theorem of Calculus", the derivative of $\int_a^t f(\tau)d\tau$, with respect to t, is f(t) so the derivative of $t\int_0^t h(\tau)d\tau$, by the product rule is $\int_0^t h(\tau) d\tau+ t h(t)$.  Similarly, the derivative of $\int_0^t \tau h(\tau) d\tau$ is $t h(t)$.